# fancy way to print out a range of a list starting with an optional negative index to a positive in python

Tags: python

I was wondering if there's a one line solution to print out a range from a potential negative index to a positive.

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
x1 = 2
x2 = 5
print(a[x1:x2])  # [3, 4, 5]
```

If x1 is negative, I want it to go from the negative index to whatever x2 is. So if `x1 = -2` the result should be: `[7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

However, currently this will return an empty list.

I could solve this by

```
x1 = -2
if x1 < 0:
   x = a[x1:] + a[:x2]
   print(x) #[7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But I was wondering if there is a one line solution to this?

Comment: One line wouldn't be the best for this though... Are you looking to print all elements between two indices, ignoring the order of the two indices?

Comment: `print(a[abs(x1):x2])`

Comment: `a[-2:]` is `[7, 8]`. Of course `a[-2:5]` is error, but `a[-2:5:-1]` is `[7]`. (The index number of `a[-2]` is `7`, `a[5]` is `6` and step is `-1`.)

Comment: `print(a[x1:x2])` returns `[3, 4, 5]`?  Not `[7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`?

Comment: I updated your question to reflect what your code is actually printing, but I assume you made a typo somewhere since you thought they returned different results.  Can you update this please?

Comment: right, sorry ! I edited the question

Answer (score 3):

Use a conditional expression:

```
print( a[x1:x2] if x1>=0 else (a[x1:]+a[:x2]) )
```

Comment: sry i made a mistake in my code, I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Using `if` statements are unavoidable here, but you can turn your code into a 1-liner using the python equivalent of the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator).

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>>
>>> def list_slice(list_, start, stop):
...     return list_[start:stop] if start >= 0 else list_[start:] + list_[:stop]
>>>
>>> list_slice(a, 2, 5)
[3, 4, 5]
>>> list_slice(a, -2, 5)
[7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in my code (updated it), I wanted to go from index -2 to index 5, so [7,8,1,2,3,4,5]